# AutoMapper - Nested Generic Object mapping

Tags: object, nested, automapper

I am learning automapper for mapping the entities.

I have an object named MyResponse1 as:

```
public class MyResponse1
{
     public bool IsSuccessful {get;set;}
     public string Message {get;set;}
     public Object ReturnedObject {get;set;}
}
```

than I have MyResponse2

```
public class MyResponse2
{
     public bool IsSuccessful {get;set;}
     public string Message {get;set;}
     public Object ReturnedObject {get;set;}
}
```

MyResponse1 is the source and MyResponse2 is destination, than I have class like:

```
public class User1
{
    public int UserId {get;set;}
}
public class User2
{
    public int UserId {get;set;}
}
```

my mapping configuration is like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User1, User2>();
Mapper.CreateMap<MyResponse1, MyResponse2>();
```

now I have like:

```
MyResponse1 resp = new MyResponse1();
resp.IsSuccessful = true;
resp.Message = "User retreived.";
User1 oUser = new User1();
oUser.UserId = 1;
resp.ReturnedObject = oUser;
```

But when I do like:

```
MyResponse2 resp2 = Mapper.Map<MyResponse1, MyResponse2>(resp);
```

than resp2 has User1 as the Returned object but I want User2 as the returned object, I canot change the type of ReturnedObject because I need to send objects of different types in it.

Any idea how it can be achieved?

**Edit:**
One way out that I used is that I did it like this and it worked:

```
MyResponse2 resp2 = Mapper.Map<MyResponse1, MyResponse2>(resp);
resp2.ReturnedObject = Mapper.Map<User1, User2>(resp.ReturnedObject as User1);
```

is there any other better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot map to the destination `ReturnedObject` type since it doesn't exist when you are mapping the `MyResponse1`. What you are doing in your edit is exactly that, you are mapping explicitly to a known type.

The only way to automate the mapping would be to declare what object MyResponse2 can expect. Perhaps transforming MyResponse2 to a generics type would be a possible way to do it:

```
public class MyResponse2<T>
{
     public bool IsSuccessful {get;set;}
     public string Message {get;set;}
     public T ReturnedObject {get;set;}
}
```

Then you could generalize the mapping process like so:

```
private static void CreateMapFromUser1To<T>() where T: class {
    Mapper.CreateMap<MyResponse1, MyResponse2<T>>()
    .ForMember(destination => destination.ReturnedObject, opt => opt.Ignore()) // ignore the object
    .AfterMap((source, destination) => destination.ReturnedObject = Mapper.Map(source.ReturnedObject, source.ReturnedObject.GetType(), typeof(T)) as T);
}
```

You won't be able to map from an object to.. basically nothing so you need a destiantion type. But frankly you may have a bad design in your app and i'd recommend stepping back a taking a good look at the conversions you want to achieve

Comment: Basically I am trying to implement this approach on a .asmx web service, the design is like the web service, than a class library and than client, client calls the class library and class library calls the web service, and when web service is called, the namespaces of returned objects are changed, so I am trying to do it through automapper that the in between class library map the objects back to their original namespace instead of the webservice namespace, i think I explained it successfully, if you have any idea about it, u r more than welcome to comment on it.